# Clarification about the Lebesgue Integral of a Square of a Stochastic Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, lebesgue-integral

In the book *Introduction to Pricing Option Theory* by *Gopinath Kallianpur* & *Rajeeva L. Karandikar*, p. 8.

What does the integral 
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^t f_s^2ds
\end{equation*}
mean given $f$ is an elementary process? This could be a Lebesgue integral. But I'm just confused as to how a stochastic process squared could be Lebesgue-integrable.

Comment: $f$ has two arguments: $f=f(t,\omega)$. For each fixed $\omega$, $t\mapsto f(t,\omega)$ is just a function of time; and its integral with respect to time is, unless otherwise noted, to be understood as a Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Okay, so it's not $f$ being a random variable being squared. I get it. Thanks @AddSup.. Does this integral always exists for any elementary process? How about for any process (i.e. what could be the conditions for this integral to exists)?